# Why does the addition of oxygen render materials colourless?

Tags: redox, color

In our book, it is mentioned that $\ce{H2O2}$ (hydrogen peroxide) is used as a bleaching agent because of its oxidizing nature:
\begin{align}
  \ce{H2O2 &-> H2O + [O]}\\
 \ce{\text{coloured material} + [O] &-> \text{colourless material}}
\end{align}

Why does the second equation happen? In other words, what role does oxygen play in the absorption of light here?

Comment: The "colourless material" is essentially a different compound from the "coloured material". It isn't like mixing yellow and blue gives green. It is like mixing hydrogen and oxygen gives water which has radically different properties.

Comment: From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bleach#Mechanism_of_action), "An oxidizing bleach works by breaking the chemical bonds that make up the chromophore. This changes the molecule into a different substance that either does not contain a chromophore, or contains a chromophore that does not absorb visible light." So the oxygen basically just disrupts the region that can absorb visible like and make it colourless.

Answer (score 6):

Many organic dyes (arguably, *all* of them) produce color due to electron transitions in [conjugated $\pi$ systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugated_system). Strong oxidants (not just the peroxide, mind you, but also hypochlorite bleach and others) snap the double bonds and thus destroy these conjugated systems. So the color vanishes.

This is not applicable to *inorganic* dyes, which usually would not get bleached by peroxide. On the contrary, some transition metals ($\ce{Ti^4+,\;Cr^6+}$, and some others) which have little or no color by themselves would produce intensely colored complexes when hydrogen peroxide is added. These reactions are sometimes used in analytic chemistry to discover their presence.

Comment: Sir, Why it is not applicable to Inorganic Dyes? And what happens in the case of Ti and Cr that addition of Hydrogen Peroxide make it colourful?

Comment: Inorganic dyes don't have conjugated $\pi$ systems. As for the transition metals, why, they form some complexes with hydrogen peroxide, and it just so happens that these complexes have strong absorption bands in visible region.

Comment: "Organic dyes produce color due to electron transitions in conjugated $\pi$ systems." Could you go into more detail on how this happens, or point to a helpful source?

Comment: Also, I did read the Wikipedia page on [chromophores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromophore). It does not explain how resonance helps capture photons in the visible light range.

Comment: Well, your second question contains the answer to your first one. Conjugated π systems do not _care_ about our visible range. It just so happens that many of them have their transitions in that range.